# Translating query from Firebird to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, firebird, code-translation

I have a Firebird query which I should rewrite into PostgreSQL code.

```
SELECT TRIM(RL.RDB$RELATION_NAME), TRIM(FR.RDB$FIELD_NAME), FS.RDB$FIELD_TYPE
FROM RDB$RELATIONS RL 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RDB$RELATION_FIELDS FR ON FR.RDB$RELATION_NAME = RL.RDB$RELATION_NAME 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RDB$FIELDS FS ON FS.RDB$FIELD_NAME = FR.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE 
WHERE (RL.RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL) 
ORDER BY RL.RDB$RELATION_NAME, FR.RDB$FIELD_NAME
```

I understand SQL, but have no idea, how to work with this system tables like `RDB$RELATIONS` etc. It would be really great if someone helped me with this, but even some links with this tables explanation will be OK.

This piece of query is in C++ code, and when I'm trying to do this :

```
pqxx::connection conn(serverAddress.str());
pqxx::work trans(conn);
pqxx::result res(trans.exec(/*there is this SQL query*/));//and there is a mistake
```

it writes that:

> RDB$RELATIONS doesn't exist.

Comment: In all honesty, your current query looks like valid SQL, excepting for the table and column name syntax.  Could you post your table _schema_ (table names plus column names/types) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I add some changes to the question text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has another way of storing information about system content. This is called [System Catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html).

In Firebird your query basically returns a row for every column of a table in every schema with an additional Integer column that maps to a field datatype.

In Postgres using system tables in `pg_catalog` schema something similar can be achieved using this query:

```
SELECT 
  TRIM(c.relname) AS table_name, TRIM(a.attname) AS column_name, a.atttypid AS field_type
FROM pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_attribute a ON 
  c.oid = a.attrelid
  AND a.attnum > 0 -- only ordinary columns, without system ones
WHERE c.relkind = 'r' -- only tables
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Above query does return system catalogs as well. If you'd like to **exclude** them you need to add another JOIN to `pg_namespace` and a where clause with `pg_namespace.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'`, because this is the schema where system catalogs are stored.

If you'd also like to see datatype names instead of their representative numbers add a JOIN to `pg_type`.

---

**Information schema** consists of collection of views. In most cases you don't need the entire SQL query that stands behind the view, so using system tables will give you better performance. You can inspect views definition though, just to get you started on the tables and conditions used to form an output.

Comment: Can you help me with anouther one [query example](http://pastebin.com/z03gGjy2), and maybe you can advice me some links/books/etc specially for dummies like me)

Comment: @koshachok you already have a source of information - system catalogs and information schema. Anyways, if you need further help then post another question on SO.

Comment: ok, but how can i correlate some Firebird's names with Postgres's ?

Comment: @koshachok as I've stated - if you have another problem to solve, post it as a new question on SO :) Though, there is no "all-database-system-column-names-translator", so you have to know what your Firebird query is doing and look for that in Postgres reference manual.

Comment: I've posted, so maybe you wanna take a part in a solving this problem ? ;)

Comment: when you wrote `pg_class c` , what did this `c` mean? As i understand, you call `c` as every table which will be used in our query?

Comment: It's called table alias. Google will help you with understanding that.

Comment: but in alias we use `AS`, and there's no constructions like that

Comment: Have you even read the code you've posted in the first place? It also has aliases without `AS` ... This clause is optional ...

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the `information_schema`.

The tables are listed here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html

So for example you can use:

```
select * from information_schema.tables;
select * from information_schema.columns;
```