# Translating query from Firebird to PostgreSQL # 2

Tags: sql, postgresql, firebird

I have a SQL query :

```
SELECT TRIM(RL.RDB$RELATION_NAME), TRIM(FR.RDB$FIELD_NAME), FS.RDB$FIELD_TYPE, TRIM(RC.RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE)
    FROM RDB$RELATIONS RL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RDB$RELATION_FIELDS FR ON FR.RDB$RELATION_NAME = RL.RDB$RELATION_NAME
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RDB$FIELDS FS ON FS.RDB$FIELD_NAME = FR.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS ISS ON ISS.RDB$FIELD_NAME = FR.RDB$FIELD_NAME
            INNER JOIN RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS RC ON RC.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME = ISS.RDB$INDEX_NAME
            WHERE (RL.RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL)
                ORDER BY RL.RDB$RELATION_NAME, FR.RDB$FIELD_NAME
```

Yesterday i asked how correctly translate a query from Firebird to PostgreSQL and I'm asking once again :) . (But I'd just started working with databases and got really hard task (rewrite a big part of code, because RDBMS had been changed) ). A big part is done, but I have a problems with this translation. So, can u help me? [There is some code](http://pastebin.com/z03gGjy2) which i've translated by myself.

Comment: Not everybody is familiar with the system tables in Firebird. What does your current query do? Please describe _what_ you want to retrieve, don't just throw a query at us without explaining what it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, i didn't write this query, but how i understand It takes information from columns `relation_name`, `field_name`, `field_type`, `constraint_type`...

Comment: This is basically your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078980/translating-query-from-firebird-to-postgresql) with the extent of constraints per fields... You can't expect us to translate it all for you. Show some sample output of your query and sample table definition that correlates.

Comment: I don't see offhand why this query wouldn't work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut The query shown is a query of the Firebird system tables, so it needs to be translated to an equivalent for PostgreSQL.